# Centralizer of $\tau=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)(5\ 6\ 7\ 8)(9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14) $ in $S_{15} $ as a semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $|C(\tau)|=|S_{15}|/|Orb (\tau)|=48\cdot 4$, and that the subgroups generated by the cycles in $\tau$, but also the subgroup generated by $(1\ 5)(2\ 6)(3\ 7)(4\ 8) $, are in the centralizer. Because of the number of the elements I have $$C (\tau)=<(1\ 2\ 3\ 4),(5\ 6\ 7\ 8),(1\ 5)(2\ 6)(3\ 7)(4\ 8)>\times <(9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14)>.$$ Is it right? How can I see it as a semidirect product?

Answer (score 1):

Call the generators of $C(\tau)$, $n_1$, $n_2$ and $s$ for the first factor and $c$ for the second factor. Note that $n_1^s = n_2$ and $n_2^s = n_1$ so that $\langle n_1, n_2\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of the first factor which can then be written as $\langle n_1, n_2\rangle \rtimes \langle s\rangle$. Now we have $C(\tau) = \langle n_1, n_2\rangle \rtimes (\langle s\rangle \times \langle c\rangle)$.